# How to encrypt data at client side using eToken

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, cryptography, e-token

I am going to develop an application with Spring framework and JSP as follows:

1) When the client enters any text and presses *encrypt* button, the data should be encrypted at the client side, but that encryption should be done using eToken.

2) When the client uploads any file it should be stored in encrypted format in a database.

For that I searched on google but didn't find any helpful resources.  We are using eToken that contains a key pair using the RSA algorithm.  My problem is how to encrypt and decrypt data and files at the client side using eToken?

I am stuck here, please help me ASAP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to do this via browser, you would need to have an ActiveX or Java applet, which will do the job. The task can not be accomplished using client-side javascript.

We developed similar solution in our SecureBlackbox product, though it works for signing at the moment (we couldn't imagine a real-life use case that would require encryption).

JFYI: To do *encryption* you don't need a private key but only a public key. Public key can be exported from the token to the computer.

Comment: Mayevski thanks for rply, actually i need private key for decryption and I am also looking for applet but i don't know how to do with applet or ActiveX. Can you please provide links for both for this situation or so hints that makes me possible to develop it?

Comment: @Balasaheb The question of "how to implement an applet" is too broad to be answered in StackOverflow format. Start with writing basic applet and basic ActiveX control (which do nothing besides accepting some parameter passed via the web page and display it). When it works, start adding cryptography to it. See more on http://lolimage.com/img/ups/81781339951332103641.jpeg

Comment: Mayevski 'EldoS I am sorry but m really new for this type of programming so please can you give me snapshot for encrypting a text or file from etoken with applet...?

Comment: @Balasaheb Search google for "java pkcs11 tutorial", this will give you a good start.